# What does "pans" mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning, phrases, sentence

I am currently translating a book called "#GIRLBOSS" by Sophia Amoruso and there's a phrase I can't clarify its meaning.

"I was proud of my video project, which was a series of **pans** with Bad Religion's angst-ridden song "Infected" as the soundtrack. *Bam*, shot of the Nike factory outlet store. *Bam*, shot of money. *Bam*, shot of graveyard."

I've scanned each and every meaning of 'pan' to no avail. I think the word is describing the images of Nike, money, graveyard etc in whole, but I can't see the connection between them.

Comment: It's a cinematographic term: try [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pan#h47375323743660), but in my experience *pan* is used for horizontal turns, *tilt* for vertical turns of the camera.

Comment: I'm curious, what dictionary does not include this cinematic meaning of "pan"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I saw GEdgar's comment and agreed with it, I went and got some definitions:

> **3 . pan** 
>  *v.intr.*
>  **To pivot a movie camera along a horizontal
>   plane in order to follow an object or create a panoramic effect.**
>   *v.tr.*
>  **To pivot (a movie camera) in a specified direction.**
>  *n.* 
>  **A
>   pivoting movement of a movie camera**.

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pan)

> **pan**
>  *vb*
>  **(Film) to move (a film camera) or (of a film camera) to
>   be moved so as to follow a moving object or obtain a panoramic
>   effect**
>  *n (Film)*
>  **a. the act of panning**
>  **b. (as
>   modifier): a pan shot.**

[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pan)

> **pan**
>   *transitive verb*
>  : **to rotate (a camera, such as a motion-picture camera) so as to keep an object in the picture or
>   secure a panoramic effect**

[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pan)

> **pan**
>   *verb*
>   **1 . with object and adverbial of direction
>  Swing (a video or film camera) in a horizontal or vertical plane, typically to give a
>   panoramic effect or follow a subject.**
>   **1.1 no object, with adverbial of direction (of a camera) be swung in a horizontal or vertical plane.**

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pan)

[Camera panning Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panning_(camera))

Sorry, I may have lost my train of thought while copying and pasting, what you're looking for is "pan" as a noun, which is how it's used in your example. Note the two "A pivoting movement of a movie camera." and "Act of panning."

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer. I was looking for it as a 'noun' that I didn't know the meaning was actually a verb.

Comment: @ХалиукаБ. Yes, it's a verb, but here it's noun. Just how a "move" can be an act of "moving", a "pan" can be an act of "panning". So the "series of pans" is a series of camera panning movements. It's an easy mistake to make.